# Facebook API: Get Replies for Posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the replies based on facebook posts. An example to this is a user publish question on a status and another user replies to that status.

So far I can use the following url and get the json `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=what&type=post` but here I only get the status and don't have the option to capture the replies for it.

Here is the result at the time I execute, but when you execute again you will get a different results set yet I have no way to follow up with the any of the given id's.

```
id: "1512134078_2118135082256",
from: {
name: "Gracie Armijo",
id: "1512134078"
},
message: "What is going on with the Comedy Central Roast.  Is there a curse?  I work on the David Hasselhoff.  After that Greg Giraldo was gone.  Then I worked the Charlie Sheen roast and now Patrice O'neal.  He was so upset with all the remarks that was said about him too.  RIP Patrice..",
type: "status",
created_time: "2011-11-29T21:11:53+0000",
updated_time: "2011-11-29T21:11:53+0000"
```

I wish base on the id I could look up all the replies for this message. But so far I have not been able to do that.